# How i can add/generate DEP11 Metadata to my Debian repository generated by Aptly?

Tags: metadata, debian-packaging

I Have my own Debian repository for packages i provide. I can install packages from my repository using apt command as well, but the software center (Apper in my case) do not know any about my packages or its icons and screenshots.

Each my debian package contain appstream metadata and SVG icon.

I use appstream-generator to extract icons and metadata from packages without any errors.

```bash
appstream-generator process -c /var/lib/jenkins/asgen-config.json bullseye
appstream-generator process -c /var/lib/jenkins/asgen-config.json bookworm
appstream-generator process -c /var/lib/jenkins/asgen-config.json focal
```

The asgen-config.json file contents:

```json
{
  "ProjectName": "VitexSoftware Repo",
  "ArchiveRoot": "/var/www/html/repo.vitexsoftware.cz",
  "MediaBaseUrl": "http://repo.vitexsoftware.com/appstream/media",
  "HtmlBaseUrl": "http://repo.vitexsoftware.com/appstream/",
  "Backend": "debian",
  "Features": {
    "processDesktop": true
  },
  "Suites": {
    "bullseye": {
      "sections": ["main", "backports", "borrowed", "games"],
      "architectures": ["amd64", "i386", "armel", "armhf", "arm64"]
    },
    "bookworm": {
      "sections": ["main", "backports", "borrowed", "games"],
      "architectures": ["amd64", "i386", "armel", "armhf", "arm64"]
    },
    "focal": {
      "sections": ["main", "backports", "borrowed", "games"],
      "architectures": ["amd64", "i386", "armel", "armhf", "arm64"]
    },
    "borrow": {
      "sections": ["main", "games"],
      "architectures": ["amd64", "i386", "armel", "armhf", "arm64"]
    },
    "jammy": {
      "sections": ["main", "backports", "borrowed", "games"],
      "architectures": ["amd64", "i386", "armel", "armhf", "arm64"]
    }
  },
  "Icons": {
    "64x64":   {"cached": true, "remote": false},
    "128x128": {"cached": false, "remote": true}
  }
}
```

The generated http://repo.vitexsoftware.com/appstream/ is strange and I'm still missing the Components.yml files like in original Debian:

http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/dep11/

How i can generate DEP11 metadata for my repository ?